# jQuery Flyout Menu. Breaking an element out of its parent

Tags: html, css, shopify

I'm working on a Shopify project. I am not the designer. I need to make a flyout menu for the shop. The problem is two fold. First of all, the flyout needs to extend to the bottom of the viewport. Secondly, I'd like to bundle everything together in the Navigation Div, but I need to figure out how to break the element out of its parent and then "layer itself" over the rest of the content without moving it around.

I thought I'd just hide the menu with CSS and then use jQuery to un-hide it on rollover. I don't think that will work though. I don't know how to position the flyout so it doesn't schlep everything around.

Here's the site now:
https://hodkiewicz-zieme-and-hirthe180.myshopify.com/

Here's what it should look like: http://tinypic.com/r/35hnyox/6

Here's what's in the nav column currently. I'll probably change the structure.

```
<div id="navbar" class="green">
    <ul id="navigation">
    {% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %}
        <li><a class="green" href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
        <li><a class="green" href="#">{{ linklists.packard.title }}</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a class="green" href="#">-1930 Speedster</a></li>
                    <li><a class="green" href="#">-1929-31 Super 8</a></li>
                    <li><a class="green" href="#">-Late 1931-32 Super 8</a></li>
                    <li><a class="green" href="#">-1929-31 Standard 8</a></li>
                    <li><a class="green" href="#">-Late 1931-32 Standard 8</a></li>
                    <li><a class="green" href="#">-Rare Parts</a></li>
                    <li><a class="green" href="#">-745 Parts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="green" href="#">{{ linklists.cadillac.title }}</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a class="green" href="#">-1932-33 V12 &amp; V16</a></li>
                <li><a class="green" href="#">-1934-37 V12 &amp; V16</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a class="green" href="/cart">Cart</a></li>
        <li><a class="green" href="/checkout">Check Out</a></li>
    </ul><!--Navigation--><!--Navigation-->

    <ul class="sub-navs">
        <ul class-"sub-nav">
            <li>Carburetor</li>
            <li>Parts</li>
            <li>Manifolds</li>
            <li>Accessories</li>
            <li>Sculpture</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>

    <img id="#navbar-logo" src="{{'logo.png' | asset_url}}">
    <p id="nav-phone" class="black center bold">775.842.4282</p>
    <p class="black center nav-small bold">packardcarbs@gmail.com</p>
    <p class="black ce

nter nav-small bold">Sparks, NV USA</p>
</div><!--Navbar-->
```

Comment: Post some code for the flyout

Comment: @Josh Infiesto i can solve this issue i need working code i mean fiddle. Or provide css, javascript you have tried because for creating from scratch will take a lot of time here in you situation.

Comment: @Josh Infiesto Dear please have a look on my answer and demo link provided on that. Please let me know if any issues so i can work on that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the desired output with exact functionality required in question.

See fiddle for code : http://jsfiddle.net/NNfUb/2/

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/NNfUb/2/embedded/result

**CSS:**

```
#content
{
    position:relative;
}

#flyout_container
{
    position:absolute;
    width:175px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#107042;
    display:none;
}

.sub-nav
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:none;
}

.sub-nav li
{
    padding:5px 5px 5px 10px;
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var container = $("<div id='flyout_container'>");
        container.appendTo($("#content"));
        var contentHeight = $("#content").height();
        container.css({"height": (contentHeight + 10) + "px"});

        $("a#show_sub_nav_1").mouseover(function(){
            $("#sub_nav_1").appendTo(container).show();
            container.toggle();
            //container.show();
            var fromTop = parseInt($(this).offset().top);
            $("#sub_nav_1").css({"margin-top": (fromTop - 205) + "px"});
        });

        $("#flyout_container").mouseleave(function(){
            $("#flyout_container").hide();
        });

    });
```

I have created the above fiddle by copying your source code from your webpage and work on that. I have created the full height functionality which is taking height upto the content height and showing the sub-links as per your desired design provided in screenshot. You need to tweek the css or code if you need any changes or enhancement. It will work on every viewport.

**Note:** If any issues please let me know. I hope this will solve your problem because i have used different approach.

Comment: Singh, nice code. Thanks for taking a look at this. Sorry I was slow in getting back to you. It's the holidays here, so it's been crazy. Bounty is yours!

Comment: Thanks Bro belated marry Christmas and Happy New year in advance. Enjoy mate.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the element's position to absolute will allow you to position it accurately without interrupting the flow of the document.

```
.flyout {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px; (number of pixels from the left edge of the document)
    top: 0px;  (number of pixels from the top edge of the document)
}
```

Comment: I knew about this, and the idea occurred to me. The problem is that, If the viewport changes, the menu doesn't stay in the same place...

Comment: Ah, in that case you're after position: fixed;  I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`position: absolute` makes the position relative to the nearest non-static-positioned ancestor. So, if you change the navigation `ul` to `position: relative`, and the flyout to `position: absolute`, you will be able to set the position of the flyout menu *relative to the main navigation*. That means that even if you resize the page, the flyout will still be in the right spot.

```
#navigation {
  position: relative;
}

.flyout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
```

(You could also set `#navbar` or `#navigation > li` to `position: relative` instead.)

You'll still need to fiddle with positioning and other styles a bit, but hopefully that sets you on the right path.